# How to show all split window titles in the X11 window title?

Tags: buffers, window, frames, window-splitting, x11

If I split an Emacs frame (one X11 window) into multiple Emacs windows (with `C-x 2` and `C-x 3`) and open different Emacs buffers in different Emacs windows, Emacs frame title (X11 window title) displays only the name of the currently active buffer. (Hope I got Emacs terminology right.)

For example: assume I have three buffers open in one X11 window: `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`. X11 window title will be `a.txt` if I have `a.txt` buffer active. I instead want it to be `a.txt, b.txt, c.txt` or any other string that contains all the split buffer names.

Motivation: I use `rofi -show window` to search for windows and I often can't find an Emacs window I look for because it has the wrong split active at the moment.